# Want to extract/export 1 766 048 records from oracle SQL developer tools

Tags: oracle

I Want to extract 1 766 048 records into any file extension like (.xls,.xlsx,.csv) from Oracle SQL Developer tools.

Is there any specific keywords which can be used with select query while extracting data like (Limit, range, etc).

I'm using select statement to fetch data from multiple tables using Oracle SQL Developer tools.

Comment: "through which i can extract data in section wise" - it's not clear what your requirement is. You can do your export just with a SELECT * FROM if you want. Any query you run, can then be exported to the formats you listed - although use XLSX - the XLS is slow and prob won't work for that many records

Comment: @thatjeffsmith , you are correct. sorry first of all for my confusion question.

Comment: Once you export these records, what are you going to do with them?

Comment: @PatrickBacon, I've to give this mass records to a client. they'll have historic data and  keep as records.

Comment: So what is the problem? There's a lot of keywords in SQL, and you've set no exact criteria for us to choose any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ROWNUM:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM < 65000
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 65000 AND 130000;
```

with multiple tables:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT T1.FIELD1,
           T1.FIELD2,
           T2FIELD3
    FROM T1,
         T2
    WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
 )
WHERE ROWNUM < 65000;
```

Comment: not necessary, SQLDev will feed the rows to the excel file auto-magically...you don't need multiple queries or rownum predicates

Comment: does a single excel file can contain 1,766,048 rows?

Comment: Just noticed I'm talking to Jeff Smith :)

Comment: better question, do you really really want an excel file with that many rows in it? i've done a million rows spreadsheet. once we reach any limit, we continue the results to a new workbook in the file

Comment: probably not, excel isn't meant for that, databases are, but the OP asked how to create segments of data so he can export them to excel more easily I guess.

Comment: yeah, maybe. except changing up queries is harder? or even better, just write out to CSV and let Codd sort it out.

Comment: @user3515709 , thanks!  I've tried it is working nicely, But another doubt came from me is, if I'm extracting report till 130000 records then after how can i start to exctarct records from 130001 and till some another limit?

Comment: you can use a between like in my exemple:

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 65000 AND 130000;